# Under cabinet LED lighting on opposing sides of the kitchen - no wire in between

Tags: lighting, led, cabinets

I would like to put LED lights under the cabinets of my kitchen, and have them controlled by wall switch.

Here is the situation, I have cabinets on opposing sides of my kitchen (facing each other).  For, the other opposing two sides of the kitchen, one side is open (i.e. no wall), the other has a massive window.

Additionally, the right side cabinetry used to have fluorescent fixtures under them which were controlled by the wall switch.  Therefore, since the right side cabinetry already has the wiring, it should be pretty easy to retrofit to LED.  The left side, had nothing, so here is where I am stuck.

How can I install and control LED lights under the left side cabinetry?  If possible, I would not like to not cut walls or have visible wires.  My wife will not allow it.

This is a challenging one, hence asking for the help.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Adding two images to be more descriptive:

FYI: The red paint on the walls in Redgard since we will be tiling soon.

1. First picture shows the first set of cabinets.  The switch that has the blue tape (on the right, right of the top oven), controls the lights underneath the cabinets of this wall.  There is a wire that travels behind the wall (or the ceiling, I actually don't know) and comes out the bottom of the left most cabinet (the one next to microwave).
2. Picture of the cabinets on the opposite wall.  There are no wires going from the switch to this wall.  I know there are electrical wires going through the ceiling from the wall on picture 1 to this wall.

Further extra info: There are two more house stories above the kitchen, and I do not have an attic, so going through the 'attic' is not an option.

[image: First wall with cabinets]
[image: Second wall with cabinets]

Comment: You can use Insteon for this.  In this case you don’t need a hub either (ok to have, not required) 2477 switch for the side that has that and a fixture module for the other side.

Comment: It would be easy at the ceiling , maybe not so hard to go down a wall from the original fixture, but with no other specifics or photos we can only guess, I have done many down the walls electrical changes with a single gang box as the only opening in the wall, so with this said hire a pro because they may be able to do it and from your comments your wife won't let you try , I don't know why, but ether you have no skills or if you have no spine. That's why I left this as a comment.

Comment: Smart plug and switch. Switch is on (IF This), Then, turn plug on (That). IFTTT. If switch is off, turn plug off.

Comment: I would never use IFTTT for this application, it’s too slow (seconds of delay) and breaks if the internet connection goes offline. I suggested Insteon because there is no switching delay and once the devices are linked it still works even without a hub.

Comment: Hi Ed Beal, added a couple of pictures given your comments.  Given the extra pictures and the extra info, what do you recommend.

Comment: Hi Tyler, can you point me to the components you are referring to?

Comment: Do you already have a power source run for the LED lights on the left side? (Note that you *cannot* tap the receptacles for this)

Comment: That is a good point, I was planning on pulling a wire from receptacles and connecting to a transformer.  Is that against code?